# ngrok, pow, and devise causes redirect to local URL after sign in on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rack-pow, ngrok

I'm running `ngrok`, `pow`, and using `devise` for authentication on my Rails 4.2.1 application. When I run it locally by going to http://myapp.dev, pow works fine all across the board. I can sign in, view pages, etc.

When I set up an ngrok proxy, I get the first login page correctly (by hitting http://123.ngrok.io), and can see that it's hitting my local app. However, after I sign in, I get redirected from http://123.ngrok.io to http://myapp.dev and prompted to sign in again. My 'after_sign_in_path` is set to return a path in my app, and it works when I do it locally.

Any ideas where that interaction is failing?

Comment: I'm still working out why this behavior occurs as well. In the ngrok inspector I noticed the web request sends a X-Original-Host header that matches the temporary ngrok URL. I think most web frameworks generate their redirects for things like successful authentication based on the domain for the vhost of the web server. The trick to fixing the incorrect redirection is to get the framework to honor the X-Original-Host as the base URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your host name so the redirect doesn't happen in `default_url_options`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
...
  def default_url_options
    { host: 'hostname.com' }
  end
...
end
```